# Allowing click or raycast to only certain items at time

Tags: unity-game-engine, click

This is kind of hard to explain so I try to do my best using the following image.

[image]

So the case is this: player has selected drill from inventory and "Confirmation menu" (A, S & D) has popped up. Now the player must select one of these actions (A = accept position, S = put item back to inventory, D = keep moving object around). Before the player chooses from one of these action he should not be able to do NOTHING else.

The problem is that if the player clicks the minimap in the upper right corner a **button click** is detected and menu is opened. If the player clicks the car (detected with **Raycast**) player gets inside. If the player drags the joysticks he starts walking around (using **Unity's Joystick script**). NONE of these should be allowed.

To the question: does Unity have some kind of method to **"Prevent any kind of click detection to any other objects but these"** OR **"If mouse is not over this object do nothing when clicked"?** There probably is nothing like that so what would be the best workaround?

Because these "click to do something" actions are triggered from various places with various styles (buttons and raycasts in tens of different scripts) I try to avoid doing this by setting booleans everywhere. Open ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: You could try doing this with layers - grouping objects that can be similarly interacted with on the same layer, then just modifying a global layer mask for raycasts when you only want to interact with specific groups of objects.

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround could be via using GUI Depth (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-depth.html).

If "Confirmation menu" guiDepth is on top and all the other GUIs are below, you could add another GUI in between covering the whole screen; a Raycast would then return the first element and if it's the middle GUI just do nothing.